# Left navigation not working properly

Tags: 2013, navigation

I have created a site programmatically and I want to configure its current (left) navigation.

My code is:

```
public static void SetCurrentNavigation(SPWeb currentWeb)
{
    if (currentWeb != null)
    {
        if (currentWeb.Configuration == 2)
        {
            BreakInheritenceForCurrentNavigation(currentWeb);
            AddQuickLaunchItem("Lists", ListNames.EventsTitle, currentWeb.Url + "/Lists/" + ListNames.Events, currentWeb);
            AddQuickLaunchItem("Lists", ListNames.DiscussionTitle, currentWeb.Url + "/Lists/" + ListNames.DepartmentDiscussionUrl, currentWeb);
            AddQuickLaunchItem("Lists", ListNames.DepartmentTasksTitle, currentWeb.Url + "/Lists/" + ListNames.DepartmentTasks, currentWeb);
        }       
        currentWeb.Update();
    }
}
public static void BreakInheritenceForCurrentNavigation(SPWeb currentWeb)
{
    PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(currentWeb);
    currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    WebNavigationSettings webNavSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(currentWeb);
    pubWeb.Navigation.InheritCurrent = false;
    webNavSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;
    pubWeb.Navigation.ShowSiblings = false;
    DeleteRecentTag(currentWeb);
    pubWeb.Update();
}
public static void DeleteRecentTag(SPWeb currWeb)
{
    using (SPWeb web = currWeb)
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;

        SPNavigationNode nodeHeader = quickLaunch.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().Where(n => n.Title == "Recent").FirstOrDefault();
        if (nodeHeader != null)
        {
            quickLaunch.Delete(nodeHeader);
        }
        web.Update();
    }
}
```

I debugged the whole program and its running fine but I am not getting the navigation affected i.e. the inheritance gets break but the lists are not displayed.

After site created I checked the navigation, in that I found no options are selected in current navigation and the labels and headers are added.

Preview is as below:

[image]

[image]

I found that I need to 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to add a list or page to the quicklaunch

```
 private static void AddListToQuicklaunch(SPWeb web, string listTitle)
 {
    var list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
    if (list != null)
    {
      list.OnQuickLaunch = true;
      list.Update();
    }
 }
```

or when adding a page

```
 private static void AddPageToQuicklaunch(SPWeb web, string pageUrl, string nodeTitle)
 {
   var newNode = new SPNavigationNode(nodeTitle, pageUrl, false);
   newNode = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsLast(newNode);
   newNode.Update();
 }
```

Comment: But I made console application and used [this](http://pastebin.com/k6i1VDU0) and it works. But it is not working in my solution.